# Why putting a piece of ice in carbonated drink, generates foam?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, fluid-statics

I'm a mathematician, not a physicist.

Perhaps the cold made the liquid reduce its solubility of gas?

Comment: For gases the relationship between solubility and temperature isn't the same as for solid materials, reducing temperatures increases solubility of gases in a mixture.

Comment: Sorry you deleted your mirror question. Down votes are not always deserved. I was adding a comment. Typically one does not do such an experiment with two long narrow mirrors. One uses thousands. This is called a [diffraction grating](https://www.rp-photonics.com/diffraction_gratings.html).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the main mechanism here is rather that the ice cube provides a [nucleation site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleation) for the carbon dioxide gas to come out of solution easily. You can test this by rinsing the ice cube under some running water, making it smoother, thus reducing the amount of nucleation sites. Or, alternatively, salt or sugar your carbonated water a bit to provide an alternative nucleation sites.

Answer (score 1):

[Related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/243148/why-rough-surfaces-promote-nucleation-of-co2-in-carbonated-drinks)

This is all about nucleation sites - small rough areas that create trapped carbon dioxide bubbles that then grow until becoming too large and split, allowing a bubble to rise to the top, either releasing into the air or getting trapped by surface tension and creating a foam.

Related fun fact 1: Nucleation sites are also significant for crystal growth.

Related fun fact 2: By releasing the carbon dioxide in the drink, you are making it ever so slightly less tart.